# Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: c#, mysql

when i execute stored procedure on remote mysql from my c# code i get the generic error:
"Fatal error encountered during command execution"
total details:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution. --->  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. --->  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed.
--->  System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int32& insertedId)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int32& insertedId)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult
```

)

my c# code:

```
 internal void InsertUpdateMySql(string connectionstring, string storedprocedure)
    {
        string sLog = "internal void InsertUpdateMySql(string connectionstring, string storedprocedure)";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
        int rowsAffected = 0;
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(storedprocedure) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionstring))
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(storedprocedure);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                IAsyncResult myResult = cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(null, null);
                SetProgressinRichText("In progress\n");
                while (!myResult.IsCompleted)
                {
                    SetProgressinRichText(".");
                }
                rowsAffected = cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(myResult);
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            this.service.WriteToLog(source, sLog + "\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.service.WriteToLog(source, sLog + "\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

the sp same like that:

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE  PROCEDURE `SPInsertUpdateCity`( in SP_CityName VARCHAR(100) charset utf8, in SP_CitySynonyms varchar(100) charset utf8, in SP_CityNumberPostOffice varchar(100)) BEGIN   if(not exists(select CityID from city where CityName = SP_CityName)) then      insert into city(CityName, CityNumberPostOffice) values(SP_CityName, SP_CityNumberPostOffice);      insert into citysynonym (CityID, CitySynonymName) values(Last_insert_id(),SP_CitySynonyms);      else if(not exists( select  CitySynonymID from    citysynonym where   CitySynonymName = SP_CitySynonyms)) then    
                insert into citysynonym (CityID, CitySynonymName) values((select cityid from city where CityName=SP_CityName), SP_CitySynonyms);     end if;    end if; END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

the connection string:

```
Server=XXXX; Port=XXXX; Database=XXXX; Uid=XXXX;Pwd=XXXX;charset=utf8;default command timeout=7200;
```

but when i exceute that on local mysql it success as well!
for remote mysql i tryied to send little data (3 records) and it executed successfully, but for large data (1500 records) the execute is failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is more than one operation going on here you could have thread safety issues in your code, and could benefit from using an `AsyncWaitHandle` rather than polling on the `IsComplete` property of the `IAsyncResult`.

Comment: thanks a lot, i add while (!myResult.IsCompleted) { myResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); } and it's resolved my problem! thank again.

Answer (score 16):

I faced this problem when executing my query was taking more than my **MysqlCommand CommandTimeout** default value.So I simply increased that time and afterward I had no such error.

```
MysqlCommand cmd = new MysqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 200;
```