# MySQL fatal error during information_schema query (software caused connection abort)

Tags: mysql, .net

I'm using *MySQL server* (5.6) database extensively through its *.NET* connector (6.8.3). All tables are created with *MyISAM* engine for performance reasons. I have only one process with one thread accessing the DB sequentially, so there is no need for transactions and concurrency.

**Please note**: *this is unlikely to be a timeout configuration issue, because my query is trivial. I did read all timeout related questions (links below). Of course, I may be wrong, but saying just "increase the net_write_timeout parameter" without explaining why exactly it can be relevant here is not an answer.*

Some of my tables are created dynamically during program execution so I'm using *create on first use* idiom, with the following method to check whether the table exists:

```cs
private bool TableExists(Space baseSpace, Space extendedSpace)
{
    var tableName = GenerateTableName(baseSpace, extendedSpace);

    var sqlConnection = this.connectionPool.Take();

    this.existsCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
    this.existsCommand.Parameters["@tableName"].Value = tableName.Trim('`');

    var result = existsCommand.ExecuteScalar() as long?;

    this.connectionPool.Putback(sqlConnection);

    return result == 1;
}
```

The query inside the `existsCommand` is as follows (broken into two lines here for readability):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema' AND table_name = @tableName
```

The value of `this.existsCommand.Parameters["@tableName"].Value` variable contains the correct name of the table, that already exists in this case (`"sample_matches_A_to_A_x"`).

The `this.connectionPool.Take()` method returns the first `MySqlConnection` object from my collection of available connections that meets the following predicate:

```cs
private bool IsAvailable(MySqlConnection connection)
{
    return connection != null
        && connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open;
}
```

Usually this works correctly, for a number of hours and then suddenly an exception occurs on this line:

```cs
var result = existsCommand.ExecuteScalar() as long?;
```

With the following contents:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution

Stack trace:

> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
>
> at implementation.SampleMatchesMySqlTable.TableExists(Space baseSpace, Space extendedSpace) in C:...\SampleMatchesMySqlTable.cs:line 168

Inner exception:

> Unable to write data to the transport connection: Software caused connection abort.

Inner exception:

> Software caused connection abort.

with ErrorCode equal to `10053` and SocketErrorCode  being `System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.ConnectionAborted`

Stack trace of the innermost exception:

> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

---

I've reviewed the following possible duplicates and unfortunately they don't seem relevant here, except one:

[SHOW TABLES encountered Fatal error encountered during command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349832/show-tables-encountered-fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution)

Unfortunately, it doesn't provide enough information to decide whether it is an exact duplicate nor it's answered.

---

There relate to timeout problems. My query is small, returns only one integer, and searches for a table in a meta-table containing something like 20 other tables.

[Fatal error encountered during command execution. in C# when i use Insert Into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330506/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-in-c-sharp-when-i-use-insert-i)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895178/fatal-error-in-mysql

[MySQL Exception - Fatal Error Encountered During Data Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546115/mysql-exception-fatal-error-encountered-during-data-read)

[Fatal error encountered during data read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131429/fatal-error-encountered-during-data-read)

[Fatal error causing timeout -mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554303/fatal-error-causing-timeout-mysql)

[ADO.Net Entity framework, Fatal error encountered during data read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075506/ado-net-entity-framework-fatal-error-encountered-during-data-read)

---

Different error regarding reading the resultset:

[Fatal error encountered during command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292842/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution)

---

Syntax errors and connection string issues:

[Mysql Fatal error encountered during command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265149/mysql-fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution)

[fatal error encountered during execution... during update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440605/fatal-error-encountered-during-execution-during-update)

[Fatal error encountered during command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876119/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution)

[fatal error encountered during command execution during update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351793/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-during-update)

[fatal error encountered during command execution c# mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843613/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-c-sharp-mysql)

[Fatal error encountered during command execution with a mySQL INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467603/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-with-a-mysql-insert)

[I have Fatal error encountered during command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673881/i-have-fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution)

[MySql exception was unhandled - Fatal error encountered during command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501881/mysql-exception-was-unhandled-fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098561/mysql-fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-in-c-sharp

[Fatal Error Encounter During Command Execution MySQL VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521908/fatal-error-encounter-during-command-execution-mysql-vb)

["Fatal error encountered during command execution." mysql-connector .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279926/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-mysql-connector-net)

["Fatal error encountered during command execution."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986738/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution)

[C#, MySQL - fatal error encountered during command execution- Checked other solutions, something I am Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329549/c-mysql-fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-checked-other-solu)

Creating a view:
["fatal error encountered during command execution" when trying to add a view from MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200843/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-when-trying-to-add-a-view-fro)

---

Reading CSV files:

[Fatal error encountered during command execution while importing from csv to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754660/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-while-importing-from-csv-to-mys)

[MySQL fatal error encountered during command execution - looping through all csv files in folder for load data local infile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254274/mysql-fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-looping-through-all-csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the `IsAvailable` method as follows:

```
private bool IsAvailable(MySqlConnection connection)
{
    var result = false;

    try
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            result = connection.Ping();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ping exception: " + e.Message);
    }

    return result && connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open;
}
```

The `.Ping` call seems to be better in verifying connection's state then its properties, although it's very poorly documented. From some other sources I've read in the meantime:

an alternative is to run a simple query like `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` instead of calling `Ping`.

---

Also, there seems that sometimes a `DataReader`, even though it was disposed (everything is implemented with the `using` statement), is still attached to the connection for some brief period of time. Because of this I've modified the condition to this:

```
if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
```

The `State` property has the [`Executing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value as long as a `DataReader` is attached to it, so additionally verifying if it's `Open` at the beginning works fine here.